# Row bind Julia data frames

Tags: append, dataframe, julia

How do I append one data frame to another, akin to SQL's `union` or R's `rbind`?

Say I have data frames `A` and `B` defined as follows.

```julia
A = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3], y = [4, 5, 6])
B = DataFrame(x = [4, 5, 6], y = [7, 8, 9])
```

One way to approach this would be as follows:

```julia
C = deepcopy(A)

for i = 1:size(B, 1)
    push!(C, Array(B[i,:]))
end
```

While this works, it feels a little hacky to me. Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: Inspired by Reza's answer, an equivalent more verbose version is `vcat(A,B)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array concatenation `[A;B]` is the simplest way to add rows of one `DataFrame` to another:

```
julia> A = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3], y = [4, 5, 6]);
julia> B = DataFrame(x = [4, 5, 6], y = [7, 8, 9]);
julia> [A;B]
6x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | x | y |
|-----|---|---|
| 1   | 1 | 4 |
| 2   | 2 | 5 |
| 3   | 3 | 6 |
| 4   | 4 | 7 |
| 5   | 5 | 8 |
| 6   | 6 | 9 |
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! Out of curiosity, do you know if this is documented somewhere? It works great but I can't seem to find it in the DataFrame docs.

Comment: Entering `?DataFrame` in REPL, will printout a list of useful methods for `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question. It turns out there is a more efficient way by using the `append!` function:

```
append!(A,B)
```

This modifies the original dataframe `A`. If you want to create a new dataframe, you can do:

```
C = deepcopy(A)
append!(C,B)
```

Note this solution is more efficient that doing `C=vcat(A,B)`. Run the following code to observe memory allocation.

```
A = DataFrame(x = [1, 2, 3], y = [4, 5, 6])
B = DataFrame(x = [4, 5, 6], y = [7, 8, 9])

## method 1: deepcopy append!
@time let 
        C=deepcopy(A)
        append!(C,B)
end

## method 2: vcat
@time vcat(A,B)

## method 3: modifies A
@time append!(A,B)
```

I find respectively (27 allocations: 2.063 KiB), (78 allocations: 5.750 KiB) and (8 allocations: 352 bytes).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do `vcat(A,B)` to append two dataframes together.

If your dataframes are in an array then using the splat operator (`...`) like this `vcat(AB...)` would also work